# How can I fetch pictures from a directory into an array?

Tags: php

I am looking for a php function to grab images from a directory and load them into an array so that I can output them automatically
For example instead of creating such an array on my own:

```
$pics = array('../photos/t.png','../photos/t1.png','../photos/t2.png','../photos/t3.png','../photos/t4.png');
```

It would be much easier if I had a function that fetches all the (.jpg, .png, .jpeg, .bmp) extension files and load them into an array
 Your ideas will be very helpful.

Comment: A 2 minute Google search would've told you to use [`glob()`](http://www.php.net/glob) or to simply iterate through files (millions of scripts for that) and only select the ones matching the right extension (millions of scripts for that).

Comment: Am just a novice, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php 
$directory = "/var/site/images";
$images = array();
if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $image = realpath("{$directory}/{$entry}");
            array_push($images, $image);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

This will loop through all the files in your images directory and store their path off to the images array. You could even use a substring function to identify images as you loop through (if you have other filetypes in your images folder) and only add the allowed file types to the array.

This is not all my code, some was borrowed from the PHP manual on `readdir()`.